# OpenGL ES 2.0 vs 1.1

Tags: java, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is it worth supporting OpenGL ES 1.1 and fixed pipelines when even the most low level hardware can support 2.0 and shading languages?

After all, every iOS device for the last 2 years supports 2.0.

Comment: Your question is inaccurate. Just as the 3GS is currently the budget iPhone, the 3G was last year. Ditto last year's 8GB iPod Touch was an ES 1.1 device. So it's actually only ten months since an iOS device that doesn't support ES 2 was on sale.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 Support--
iPad               April 3, 2010     15 Months ago.---  
iPod Touch 3rd Gen September 9, 2009 22.5 Months ago.---  
iPhone 3GS         June 19, 2009     25 Months ago.---  
.....
I guess I should change that to "every 'NEW' iOS device", however I guess what i'm trying to point out is your comment is neither constructor nor does it add anything to the conversation. Just because you can type something, doesn't mean you should.You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: Try re-reading my comment. You could walk into a shop and buy a brand new latest-model iOS device that doesn't support ES 2.0 as recently as September 7, 2010. It is therefore untrue to say that "every iOS device for the last 2 years supports 2.0", since many rolled off production lines and were bought by consumers that don't. I'd also suggest you keep your personal attacks for the playground in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (moneyToSupportES1_1 > moneyToBeMadeBySupportingES1_1)
{
    [self setSupportES1_1:NO];
}
```

I doubt it would be worth your time, especially if you can get it to work in some limited way without writing to 1.1 standards (solid textures rather than shaders, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not really.  Especially if you're only targeting iOS users.